# service reference and configurable URL

Tags: c#, .net

After adding a service reference. In App.config you get something like this:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://172.31.82.70:8003/TestMatchService/TestMatchService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestMatchService1"
            contract="TestMatchServiceV2.ITestMatchService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestMatchService1" />
    </client>
```

I want to add a custom app setting like this:

```
<add key="Server" value="172.31.82.70"/>
```

How can I modify the endpoint to pick up the IP address from the app setting?

Comment: You cannot pick parameters from another section in config file. Why would you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an endpoint programmatically, so you just do this combined with reading the config from your appSettings as you would normally:

```
// Read this from your config instead...
string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"]
string address = $"http://{server}:8003/TestMatchService/TestMatchService";

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(address);
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITestMatchService>(binding, endpoint);
ITestMatchService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

You won't need anything in the WCF part of the config file anymore.